# std::bad_alloc: out_of_memory: CUDA error

Tags: out-of-memory, svm, gridsearchcv, rapids, cuml

I have this code:

```
import cudf
import cuml
import cupy as cp
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from cuml.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from cuml.metrics import accuracy_score
import pandas as pandas
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def preparaDatos(y,pathMetadata,pathMatrizUnitigs) :
        
    print("Preparing data for modeling...")
    y_column = pandas.read_csv(pathMetadata,index_col=0,delimiter=';')
    y_column = y_column.dropna(subset=[y]) 
    y_column = y_column[y]
      
    X = pandas.read_csv(pathMatrizUnitigs, sep="\t", index_col=0, low_memory=False)
    X = X.transpose()
    X = X[X.index.isin(y_column.index)] 
    
    y_column = y_column[y_column.index.isin(X.index)]
        
    ordered_indices = y_column.index
   
    X_ordered = X.loc[ordered_indices]

    return X_ordered, y_column

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def main():
    espacioTrabajo = ""
    archUnitigs = "graph.nodes"
    archMatrizUnitigs = "salida_Unitig_caller.rtab"
    archMetadata = "metadata.csv"
    archMatrizUnitigsFiltrada = "salida_Unitig_caller_gt90.txt"
    pathArchUnitigs = espacioTrabajo + archUnitigs
    pathMetadata = espacioTrabajo + archMetadata
    pathArchMatrizUnitigsFiltrada = espacioTrabajo + archMatrizUnitigsFiltrada


        
    classField="VC"
    X, y = preparaDatos(classField,pathMetadata,pathArchMatrizUnitigsFiltrada)

    
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
    
   
    X_train_cudf = cudf.DataFrame(X_train)
    X_test_cudf = cudf.DataFrame(X_test)
    y_train_cudf = cudf.Series(y_train)
    y_test_cudf = cudf.Series(y_test)
    
 
    X_train_cudf = X_train_cudf.astype('float32')
    y_train_cudf = y_train_cudf.astype('float32')
    
    # Definir los parámetros a probar en la búsqueda de cuadrícula
    params = {
             'C': [0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1, 1, 1.3, 1.5, 1.7, 2.0, 3.0, 4,0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
             'gamma': [0.000001, 0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10],
             'kernel': ['linear', 'poly' , 'rbf' , 'sigmoid']
     }
    
   
    svm_model = cuml.svm.SVC(cache_size=10240)
    
    
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=svm_model, param_grid=params, cv=3, n_jobs=-1)
    
    print("Performing GRID search...")
   
    grid_search.fit(X_train_cudf.to_numpy(), y_train_cudf.to_numpy())
    
    best_params = grid_search.best_params_
    
    print("Best params: ")
    print(best_params)
    
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-24.02/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File ~/Documentos/ML/Python/Pruebas/SVM_GPU_6.py:106
    main()

  File ~/Documentos/ML/Python/Pruebas/SVM_GPU_6.py:85 in main
    grid_search.fit(X_train_cudf.to_numpy(), y_train_cudf.to_numpy())

  File ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-24.02/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:1474 in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)

  File ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-24.02/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py:970 in fit
    self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)

  File ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-24.02/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py:1527 in _run_search
    evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))

  File ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-24.02/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py:947 in evaluate_candidates
    _warn_or_raise_about_fit_failures(out, self.error_score)

  File ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-24.02/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:536 in _warn_or_raise_about_fit_failures
    raise ValueError(all_fits_failed_message)

ValueError: 
All the 3168 fits failed.
It is very likely that your model is misconfigured.
You can try to debug the error by setting error_score='raise'.

Below are more details about the failures:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3168 fits failed with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/veronica/anaconda3/envs/rapids-24.02/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 895, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/home/veronica/anaconda3/envs/rapids-24.02/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cuml/internals/api_decorators.py", line 188, in wrapper
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "svc.pyx", line 545, in cuml.svm.svc.SVC.fit
  File "svc.pyx", line 547, in cuml.svm.svc.SVC.fit
MemoryError: std::bad_alloc: out_of_memory: CUDA error at: /home/veronica/anaconda3/envs/rapids-24.02/include/rmm/mr/device/cuda_memory_resource.hpp
```

I would like to know if it would be possible to optimize the code so that this error does not occur. I've been looking for a way to set the amount of available memory for GridSearchCV but haven't found the option. My other question is whether it's a good practice to use so many parameters to find the best model or if another strategy is commonly used?

I have a 11th Gen Intel Core i5-11400 @2.60GHz and a NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Ti GPU (12.88 GB available).

The version of rapids is 24.02 and I am running the code using Spyder 3.10.

Comment: How large is your data? You may want to avoid calling .to_numpy(). It seems like you have the data on the GPU already (as cuDF DataFrames) and then you're copying it to the host memory (as numpy arrays) and back to the device (for cuml to process). You may have too many copies of your data on the GPU.

Comment: X is 211 x 271774 and y is 43 x 271774. I can´t avoid calling .to_numpy() since grid_search.fit()  only accepts numpy arrays. I made a modification in the code so that fit processes batches of 10 records, but I'm still getting the error.